# How can i get a button to add an item to an arraylist then to a listview in another fragment activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, arraylist

I have a fixed tab layout with 3 tabs. I am trying to have a button in tab1 to add items into a listview in tab2 using `ArrayList`, both of them extends `Fragment`. The below code works only when the the activity extends Activity. Can anyone help me out with an answer to the fix of the problem.

I did some testing with an independent activity with a button that adds to listview inside that same activity layout, this is the one that works

**MainActivty**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView LView;
ArrayList <String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);


}

public void sendToListView(View view) {

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList); //Sets the adapter to hold the List View
    LView.setAdapter(adapter); //Adds to the List View
    arrayList.add("Thursday");

}
```

}

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="add"
    android:onClick="sendToListView"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This MainActivity extends Fragment and has an error when i try to implement the same operation**

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private ListView LView;
ArrayList <String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
            container, false);
    LView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList); //Here is the error
            LView.setAdapter(adapter); //Adds to the List View
            arrayList.add("Thursday");
            break;
    }
}
```

}

How can i get this working for Fragments, and how could i hve this operation be sent to the other Fragment activity tab and saved to SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have more to do with just your general methodology in your fragments. In your activity, you are using the XML to specify a method to run on click of a Button, which makes a whole lot of sense. In the fragment instead you are overriding the method onClick but not activating it by any means. Instead I would again define a button in your fragment XML and either findViewById in your fragment and add your on click method there instead of how you are currently doing it. Alternatively you could just add a onclick handler to the view inside of your fragment if you do indeed want the user to be able to click anywhere in your fragment.

```
 Button yourFragmentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourFragementButtonId);
 yourFragmentButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

      //Sets the adapter to hold the List View
      LView.setAdapter(adapter); //Adds to the List View
      arrayList.add("Thursday");
   }
 });
```

Comment: I have something to share with you, I tried doing this with extending ListFragment like with this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2mMwWiZBmE and it works independently in a new project, but with the one i have already it doesn't work. My custom  PageAdapter gives me an error when i extend one activity with ListFragment and the others with Fragment. And if i try to extend all with ListFragment it crashes. Any idea on a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're confunsing the concepts of Activity and Fragment. Having a Fragment does not exclude the necessity for an underlying Activity, because every Fragment needs to be plugged on an Activity to be displayed as it is stated in the AndroidDevelopers:

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity

To see more on this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html .

But, even considering that you attached the fragment correctly and that you are using the right layout on it, you still need to do a few changes if you need to use a fragment here:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ListView LView;
    ArrayList <String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
            container, false);
        LView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        Button myButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList); //Here is the error
                LView.setAdapter(adapter); //Adds to the List View
                arrayList.add("Thursday");
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting an error in the ArrayAdapter<String> line, it's underlined red.Saying "Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(com.ub.rdm.listview.MainActivity, int, java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>)'"

Comment: Change new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList); to new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);